# Can I declare globals in a subroutine in perl?

Tags: perl, scope, global-variables

Can I declare globals in a subroutine in perl with `use strict`?

Consider the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# $Id: foo,v 1.5 2019/02/21 10:41:08 bennett Exp bennett $

use strict;
use warnings;

initialize();

print "$lorem\n";

exit 0;

sub initialize {
    # How would one delcare "$lorem" here such that it is available as
    # a global?

    $lorem = <<_EOM_
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
_EOM_
    ;
}
```

Note that I'm not asking if (ab)using globals in this fashion is a good idea;  I'm certain that it isn't.

I've tried a few combinations of `our` and `$main::`, but they all fail in just the manner you might expect them to.

At this point, I'm just curious.  Can it be done?
I wonder if some sort of shenanigans with the `BEGIN` block would work.

The following will work, but as @simbabque points out, it's ugly:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# $Id: foo,v 1.7 2019/02/21 19:48:26 bennett Exp bennett $

use strict;
use warnings;

initialize();

printf("$main::lorem\n");

exit 0;

sub initialize {
    # How would one delcare "$lorem" here such that is is available as
    # a global-ish?

    our $lorem = <<_EOM_
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
_EOM_
    ;
}
```

Comment: `our` and `$main::` are not global. They are package variables. You need to be more clear. Is all you want to do to use the variable outside of the scope of `initialize`?

Comment: I'd settle for declaring a package $main:: variable within a subroutine.

Comment: Not really.  I'd like the `initialize` subroutine to declare and initialize all of the globals (or package $main::) variables.  It's more a matter of curiosity at this point.

Comment: Have you considered writing OOP code instead? Make this an object, that would make a lot more sense.

Comment: No, my question was what I meant.  Sort of.  As a matter of curiosity, I was wondering if you could declare $main:: variables from within a sub.  After reading a bit about the compiler, I don't see how.  Not easily, anyway.

Comment: @simbabque, Re "*`our` and `$main::` are not global. They are package variables.*", 1) Package variables are global variables (visible everywhere). 2) `our` variables are lexical variables (aliased to package variables).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your specific example, you don't need a *global* variable.

Perl has *package variables*. Those are created with `our` and can also be accessed with `$namespace::` (where `main` is the default namespace, and `$::` works for that as well). Those are *global*, but we rarely call them that.

You need to keep in mind that `our` makes a *lexical* alias, so if you declare it inside the sub, it will not be available outside, because there is no lexical alias in that larger scope.

```
use strict;

sub foo {
    our $bar = 123;
}

foo();
print $bar; # error
```

You need to declare the variable in a larger scope.

```
use strict;

our $bar;

sub foo {
    $bar = 123;
}

foo();
print $bar;
```

This will work, because `$bar` is now available in the file's scope.

All of this only applies when `use strict` is turned on. If you don't *declare* a variable, it will automatically become a package variable. However, if you turn on strict, you have to declare all variables. Therefore you need to be explicit.

You can also use `my` if you declare it outside of the sub.

```
use strict;

my $bar;

sub foo {
    $bar = 123;
}

foo();
print $bar;
```

Since you're doing this in a script and there is no explicit package declaration, I think it's safe to assume there are no other modules involved. In that case, it does not matter if you use `my` or `our`.

If you were using this in a package with different files involved it would make a difference. Variables declared on the file scope with `my` are kind of *private*, as there is no way to access them from the outside directly.

```
package Foo;
use strict;

my $bar = 123;

### other file
use Foo;

# no way to get $bar as there is no $Foo::bar
```

But if you use `our` (or the outdated `use vars`) it will become a package variable.

```
package Foo;
use strict;

our $bar = 123;

### other file

use Foo;
print $Foo::bar;
```

---

> Can I declare globals in a subroutine in Perl?

**Yes**, you can declare package variables in a subroutine with `our`. But you can't access them as lexical variables outside the scope they've been declared in, so you need to access them with their fully qualified package name, and that is ugly.

Comment: @ErikBennett it's a "this is how you can do what I think you want to do", because your question is a little unclear. There is no concept of _global_ in Perl.There are namespaces and scopes. The only things that are truly _global_ are [special variables listed in perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#SPECIAL-VARIABLES), like `$$` and `$^V` and so on. Those are often also called _super-global_. But you cannot make your own of these.

Comment: The first code sample does print 123. An error is thrown only when

    use strict

is enabled.

Comment: @sinbabque Isn't this nonsense? `our` doesn't make a lexical variable - `my` does. All `our` does is to allow you to address a (globally accessible) package variable without the package name. In a main package, for instance, you'd normally use `$::variablename`, but after saying `our $variablename`, you can just use `$variablename`.

Comment: @Silvar run this: `perl -E 'package Foo; our $bar = 1; { our $asdf = 2; } say $asdf; package main; say $bar;'` Then remove stuff to play around with it. `our` makes a package variable, but it also imports it only into the lexical scope. Replace `say $asdf` with `$Foo::asdf` to make it work.

Comment: @Silvar `our` makes a "lexical alias to a package variable". It declares it available under that name in the current lexical scope, *even if that scope changes packages afterward*, it will still refer to the same package variable. But if you exit the lexical scope of that `our` the alias will not be available.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is "no".  Not with `use strict`.  Among the features of `use strict` is checking whether or not you're using a variable before it's declared.

The notion of wanting to do just that, as I did above, is at odds with the compile time checks of `use strict`.

Thanks to @simbabque for helping me think through this more clearly.

Rather than remove the `use strict`, I'm going to move the ugliness of the huge `$lorem` type variables (and there's a lot of them) to a separate package.

-E

Comment: You know, if they are all fixed values, there is no need to make them variables. You can make them constants (or subs).

Comment: Tell me more.  Most of them are ugly HTML code that messes with `perl-mode` in emacs.

Comment: Oh. Maybe you should just switch to a template system? If you were to move those into their own module, you're halfway there anyway.

Comment: Nah.  The HTML is about 1% of the output, and it's pretty basic.  I am curious about the best practices `sub` usage, though.  Do you have a link?

Comment: To get a constant that always evaluates to 10, just use `sub ten_constant { 10 }`. Can't modify that!

Comment: @Silvar well technically, you can. `perl -E 'sub ten {10} say ten(); *ten = sub {2}; say ten()'`

Comment: @simbabque, @Silvar, @ikegami, (and everyone else) Is this "answer" correct enough that I can mark it closed?  Should I just blast it?  Or leave it for the next person who wants to use a variable before declaring it while `use strict` is in force?

Comment: You can only ping one person per comment. Only I was notified because my name came first.

Comment: I do not want to coerce you into accepting my answer, but I believe you should accept the answer that actually answers your question. You didn't ask for a better solution to your production code that you've not shown us, but that's what you explain in your answer. You asked _Can I declare globals in a subroutine in Perl?_. I'll edit mine to make it even more clear.

Comment: Your answer confuses me, and here's why:  You say, "You need to declare the variable in a larger scope."  I believe this to be true (now).  Then later on, you say, "Yes, you can declare package variables in a subroutine with `our`."  Doesn't that just provide access to the outer (package) variable?  The actual declaration still has to occur in the outer scope?  I'm not trying to be difficult, just trying to make sure I understand the post.

Comment: The whole reason this is even coming up is that I started writing in perl back in the early 1990s when there were only globals and locals.  At the time, it was fairly common, if somewhat ill-considered to have a subroutine called `initialize_globals`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188852/discussion-between-erik-bennett-and-simbabque).